# how to modify in dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

The groups_per_user function receives a dictionary, which contains group names with the list of users. Users can belong to multiple groups. Fill in the blanks to return a dictionary with the users as keys and a list of their groups as values

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    # Go through group_dictionary
    for ___:
        # Now go through the users in the group
        for ___:
            # Now add the group to the list of
# groups for this user, creating the entry
# in the dictionary if necessary

    return(user_groups)

print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],
        "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
        "administrator": ["admin"] }))
```

Comment: If you have specific issues while solving this yourself you can ask here.

Comment: Okay. What do you think should go in the blanks? Did you try to put something in the blanks? Did it work? If not, what happened? If you can't think of anything that goes in the blanks... what is your understanding of how `for` works in Python? Do you have any lecture notes that you can review?

Comment: I proposed an answer below because I found the problem nice to think about, not because the way you asked the question. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    for group in group_dictionary:
        for user in group_dictionary[group]:
            if user not in user_groups:
                user_groups[user] = []
            if group not in user_groups[user]:
                user_groups[user].append(group)
    return user_groups

mylist = {"local": ["admin", "userA"],
          "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
          "administrator": ["admin"] }

print(groups_per_user(mylist))
# {'admin': ['local', 'public', 'administrator'], 'userA': ['local'], 'userB': ['public']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    # Go through group_dictionary
    for group in group_dictionary:
        # Now go through the users in the group
        for user in group_dictionary[group]:
            try:
                user_groups[user].append(group)
            except KeyError:
                user_groups[user] = [group]
            # Now add the group to the list of
# groups for this user, creating the entry
# in the dictionary if necessary

    return(user_groups)
```

Comment: I really like your solution with try/except. thanks for tip ... I will try to use this in my future code, it makes the code easier to read (in comparison to my answer).

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    for grp, users in group_dictionary.items():
        for user in users:
            if user in user_groups:
                user_groups[user].append(grp)
            else:
                user_groups[user] = [grp]

    return (user_groups)
```

Output of your `print` statement:

```
{'admin': ['local', 'public', 'administrator'], 'userA': ['local'], 'userB': ['public']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    for key,users in group_dictionary.items():
        for user in users:
            user_groups[user]=[]
    for key in user_groups.keys():
        for ke,value in group_dictionary.items():
            for i in value:
                if(key==i):
                    user_groups[key].append(ke)
    return(user_groups)
print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],"public"["admin","userB"],"administrator": ["admin"] }))
```

Comment: This is the correct output :
{'admin': ['local', 'public', 'administrator'], 'userA': ['local'], 'userB': ['public']}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    # Go through group_dictionary
    for key,value in group_dictionary.items():
        # Now go through the users in the group
        for letter in value:
            if letter in user_groups:
                user_groups[letter] += [key]             
            else :
                user_groups[letter] = [key]
            
    return(user_groups)

print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],
    "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
    "administrator": ["admin"] }))
```